# Get the records from database with records having present date or upcoming date

Tags: android

I have a folowing code for getting records from a datbase in ascending order
        public Cursor fetchAllRemindersD() {

```
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY, KEY_PHONE,KEY_DATE_TIME}, null, null, null, null,KEY_DATE_TIME +  " ASC");
}
```

The dates are stored in string format.
What should i do inorder to get the records with dates having either present date or upcoming  dates..

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
mDB.query(
    DATABASE_TABLE, 
    new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_PHONE, KEY_DATE_TIME}, 
    KEY_DATE_TIME + " >= ?", 
    new String[]{Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())}, 
    null, null, KEY_DATE_TIME +  " ASC");
```

... assuming your dates are stored in epoch format.

Comment: as i have strored date in string format, how can i convert to epoch format and use as you said

Comment: Then you need to update your database to store them as longs. You won't be able to apply select criteria to those columns otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on in which format you store dates in your database. If you store dates in 'YYYYMMDD' format you can easily apply '<' and '>' operators in your query to get present and upcoming records. For example '20111110' is always greater than '20111109'.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you have stored the data in the db. If its a unixtime stamp then get the current date and return entries that are higher then that value.

You will need something like the following

```
long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;


String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE +" WHERE" + KEY_DATE_TIME + "=?";
mDb.rawQuery(myQuery, new String[] {timeStamp});
```